# Classic Unix lockfiles: detect stale locks without a race

Tags: unix, language-agnostic, posix

A "classic Unix lockfile", as implemented by e.g. [liblockfile](https://github.com/miquels/liblockfile), is an ordinary text file with a mutually agreed-upon name, containing the decimal PID of the process holding the lock.  A program claims the lock by creating the lockfile atomically (e.g. with `O_EXCL` or `link`) and releases the lock by deleting it.

Some implementations, such as liblockfile, attempt to detect stale lockfiles.  If the lockfile already exists, they open it, read the PID, and call `kill(pid, 0)`; if this call fails with ESRCH, they delete the lockfile and retry creation.  I believe this logic, by itself, is unsafe due to this three-way race:

```
process 1      process 2                                 process 3
holds lock
               open(tmp2, WRONLY|CREAT|EXCL) -> fd21     open(tmp3, WRONLY|CREAT|EXCL) -> fd31
               write(fd21, pid2)                         write(fd31, pid3)
               close(fd21)                               close(fd31)
               link(tmp2, lock) -> EEXIST
               open(lock, RDONLY) -> fd22
               read(fd22) -> pid1
               close(fd22)
unlink(lock)
exit(0)
               kill(pid1, 0) -> ESRCH 
                                                         link(tmp3, lock) -> 0
               unlink(lock)
               link(tmp2, lock) -> 0
```

after which process 2 has stolen the lock from process 3.

Is there a way, using only standard POSIX.1-2008 APIs, to prevent this and all other possible races in stale lockfile detection?  If it can't be done within POSIX, can it be done with some relatively common system's extensions?

Comment: Use an exclusive file lock (Established with `flock()` or `fcntl()` - just be consistent about which one is used) instead of relying on pids.

Comment: @Shawn If you can explain how to use `flock` or `fcntl` locking to fix the race conditions *in the algorithm described in the question*, I'm all ears, but I don't see how to do it, because `flock` type locking works on the inode and each of the three processes in the race are looking at a different inode. Changing to e.g. a lock file that always exists (so all processes are applying `flock` to the same inode) is not an option due to backward compatibility constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've clarified that, for compatibility, the lockfile inode is remade with each locker, I'd suggest [`F_SETLK`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html#)ing the *lockfile* before unlinking it.

The inability to lock it means either the lockfile is live, or another competing process is about to unlink.

```
open(tmp, O_CLOEXEC|O_EXCL|...) -> fd
set_cloexec(fd)  // if no O_CLOEXEC
fcntl(fd, F_SETLCK, { .l_type = F_WRLCK, ...} )
write(fd, my_pid, ...)
link(tmp, lockfile) -> EEXIST

  // stale lockfile?
  lfd = open(lockfile, ...)
  // Give up if EACCES or EAGAIN
  fcntl(lfd, F_SETLCK, { .l_type = F_WRLCK, ...} ) -> 0
  unlink(lockfile)
  close(lfd)
```

You can skip the *kill* logic in this case, too.

Comment: This sounds promising.  I am going to have to do a bunch of testing before accepting an answer.